# Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [mybatis-spring.xml]:

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, mybatis

IDE is IDEA

**Throw the exception When me click install of maven ,but i click run button is success.**

maven compile is also success.

I don't know what i did wrong

What this is question?

How i should to do?

HELP ME  THANK!

**Input Exception:**

```
    testFindByAccount(com.myth.test.TestUserRepositoryMapper)  Time elapsed: 1.115 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
  'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [mybatis-spring.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.myth.test.TestUserRepositoryMapper.onBefore(TestUserRepositoryMapper.java:14)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
    PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        ... 42 more
```

**mybatis xml config file:**

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:dbConnection.properties"/>


<bean class="com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource" id="dataSource" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc_url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc_username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc_password}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    </bean>

  <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean" name="sqlSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mappers/*.xml"/>
    </bean>
```

**Who can help me, Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing class is located in [spring-jdbc](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc). You obviously does not have this dependency in your `pom.xml`.

Add the version that corresponds to the spring version you are using to dependencies section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you for answer sincerely  ,it to me very good, I'm is a java Beginner,the exception is confusing..